# Windows Command line PHP

Tags: php, windows, command-line

I want to run my PHP script from the commandline.

I have set the PHP up as a global variable under PATH but when I insert

```
"C:\Users\PC\Documents\xampp\htdocs\code\index.php" -- arg1
```

it simply opens the file instead of running the script in CMD

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you'd have to associate .php files with php.exe, so that php.exe gets fired up and passed the .php as an argument, much like .bat is associated with cmd.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
cd C:\Users\PC\Documents\xampp\htdocs\code\
php index.php --arg1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the folder where: php.exe /path/to/file.php --arg1

Associate the .PHP extension with a file type. This is done by running the following command:

```
assoc .php=phpfile
```

Associate the phpfile file type with the appropriate PHP executable. This is done by running the following command:

```
ftype phpfile="C:\PHP5\php.exe" -f "%1" -- %~2
```

You can find full instructions here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php